# VB.NET - Check for some text in ADB output

Tags: android, vb.net, text, output, adb

I need to check if `adb devices`'s output contains the word `device`.
`adb device`'s output is

```
List of devices attached
[something]        device
```

And I want to check for the `device` after `something`.

I tried with

```
If ADB_Devices_Output.Contains("  device") Then
   ' Something
End If
```

But it doesn't work. If I try with

```
If ADB_Devices_Output.Contains("device") Then
   ' Something
End If
```

It finds the `device` contained in `List of devices attached`.

What should I do?

Comment: It's probably a tab in front of `device`

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger and examine the text you have captured?

Comment: @Simon You were right, it actually was a tab... I checked it with the debugger. Thanks for your advice :)